# Copying string from source printing strange string of characters

Tags: c, string, lexer

Im making a lexer and I'm trouble copying a string from my file buffer to the string property of the constructor. Here is the code i'm using to copy a string from the buffer.

```
    static token_t* lexer_str(lexer_t* lexer) {
    size_t str_len = 0;

    while (true) {
        if (lexer->len < 1) {
            error_new(lexer->errors, lexer->len, lexer->pos, "Unterminated string.");
            return NULL;
        } else if (lexer_look(lexer, 0) == '\"') {
            lexer_adv(lexer, 1);
            break;
        } else {
            lexer_adv(lexer, 1);
            str_len++;
        }
    }

    char* string = malloc(str_len);
    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < str_len; idx++)
        string[idx] = lexer->src[lexer->ptr - str_len + idx];

    token_t* token = token_new(lexer, _str);
    token->string = string;
    return token;
}
```

And here is the buffer.

```
"la la la" "me me me"
```

and here is the output, the string is coming out as "²²²²\"

```
Type:0 {
        Line:   1
        Pos:    0
        Number: 10715872
        Real:   10715872
        String: ²²²²\
}
```

Why is this happening? Is it just me reading memory from the wrong place. Any help for how I could correctly copy the string into the token would be appricated.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `char* string = malloc(str_len);` is too short, and your string is not null terminated after the copy (you copy a buffer given offset and len, the buffer does not contain an ending null char)

change to:

```
char* string = malloc(str_len+1);  // 1 byte more
for (size_t idx = 0; idx < str_len; idx++)
   string[idx] = lexer->src[lexer->ptr - str_len + idx];
 string[str_len] = '\0';  // don't forget to null-terminate
```

If the source is, say, empty, then you have a non-null terminated string in `string`

Comment: I changed `string[str_len] = 0` to `string[str_len + 1] = 0` but that caused it to print this weird symbol `═`

Comment: @Hedron: `string[str_len] = 0;` was correct, although I'd prefer `string[str_len] = '\0';`.

Comment: BTW can you print `lexer->src[lexer->ptr - str_len]` just to be sure the source is ok?

Comment: `printf("%s\n", lexer->ptr - str_len);` throws an access violation exception. However I think I'm making progress, now it is printing `═══════` which has the correct length; however, obviously not the right characters. Sorry for the trouble I'm fairly new to C and I'm spoiled from CPP.

Comment: I meant: `printf("%s\n", lexer->src[lexer->ptr - str_len]);`. Of course it crashes otherwise: you're converting an integer to a string... BTW what's the type of `lexer->ptr` ?

Comment: So just to clear things up. lexer->ptr is an unsigned int(size_t) and yes `printf("%s\n", lexer->src[lexer->ptr - str_len]);` still causes a read access error.

Comment: I got it, thanks for all your help guys!